# Troubleshooting meteor application

Tags: meteor, supervisord

I am running a meteor application on my server. When I restart my application after a system reboot, sometimes it fails to start in the first few attempts. I am using supervisor to manage the processes. I cannot find any logs except supervisor logs which only show failed retries to start the application. Can anyone help me how can I do the troubleshooting and learn why the application fails to start?

Comment: you might want to include the logs here. Also, do you have issues manually restarting the application?

Comment: @Jesse include logs where? The issue is sometimes all works fine but at times it

Comment: Show the log ouput in your post. Context helps people help you. A new account posting a vague question with little context doesn't really allow for a helpful discussion.

Comment: @Jesse, I'm sorry I'm a newbee and as I said I have no logs except supervisor saying "meteor exited" and no other information regarding the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the problem. Meteor application was dying everytime I was trying to restart supervisor with a custom script because the script would not stop the previous instance and try to start a new instance on the same port, causing meteor to exit. So the problem was with the way I was using supervisor to manage my meteor application and not with the application actually.